# hide layout out side the area and move layout from right to left?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-animation, android-menu

I have one scenario as below image shows,

Simply I want to create slider from right to left. 
That should overlaps the screen.

I tried custom slider [MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer](https://github.com/chemalarrea/DemoSlidingDrawer/blob/master/DemoSlidingDrawer/src/it/sephiroth/demo/slider/widget/MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer.java)
I also Tried custom Sliding Drawer.
But the problem is it is not that much smooth navigation.

So I want to create two layout 
one layout for my fragments, and second is for my menu layout but it should 80% moved at right side and 20% visible and when i click on visible area it should smoothly appeared from right to left.

like below fig. 1 & 2

I am currently using one fragment with slide in out animation from left. But  problem is I need to create separate arrow button and hide and show when fragment shows ans removed.

[image]

I just want to create functionality with fig 1 & 2 without separate  menu arrow button.

I want to implement desire things with simple layout witch partial moved 80% right offset. and when click 20% visible area it should appear 100% with smooth animation from right to left.

please let me know if it is possible via one separate layout partial moved right side and when click visible area it should smoothly move to 100% visible.

any suggestions are well come.

Thanks,

Comment: you mean you want to know how to make slider?

Comment: yes I know slider, But I want to implement desire things with simple layout witch partial moved 80% right offset. and when click 20% visible area it should appear 100% with smooth animation from right to left.